# Banner hugged to the bottom

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, admob, frame

I'm using AdMob to display ads in my app. The problem is i cant seem to hug to the bottom always.

How can i make the bannerView_ stay at the bottom when people are scrolling?

This is my banner frame:

```
[bannerView_ setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-bannerView_.frame.size.height, 320, 50)];
```

Comment: At where you are adding bannerView_ ?

Comment: [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My basic suggestion is.

First create `scrollView` and add all your controllers on it and add `scrollView` in `self.view` as `subView.`

Then after ( over `scrollView`) create `UIView` *(name is **bannerView**)* and also add this view in `self.view` as `subView.`

So basically this **bannerView** is overlapping on the `scrollView` and it stay visible when you scroll up/down.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this bannerView_ to UIWindow. i.e to [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0]; .

By doing so bannerView_ will be added and will be independent of other views.

This will be helpful in case you want to present your ad on different view controllers and don't want to handle its interference with the base view of different view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow my code in which banner will be stick at bottom

```
GADBannerView  *bannerView_ = [[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait] autorelease];
bannerView_.adUnitID = AdMob_ID;
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;

UIView  *bannerView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height - bannerView_.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, bannerView_.frame.size.height)];
bannerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
[bannerView addSubview:bannerView_];
[self.view addSubview:bannerView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:bannerView];
[bannerView release];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Comment: When i scroll it does not follow the bottom and it hides the last cell.

Comment: Decrease your scrollview's height and increase contentsize